# Parent page is refreshed in asp.net despite using return false in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a parent page which has link to pop up. When I pick the values from pop up and hit 'Ok' button in
pop up, those values are retrieved and placed in parent page text box controls and with in a span of second the page is refreshed automatically and values are reset. I already placed return false at the end of Javascript function that displays the popup.  I placed break points and everything looks fine (return false statement is hit). The parent page button has 'onclick' attribute added in Page_load function of code behind. To know whats happening, I added the 'window.onbeforeunload' function at the end (after body tag ends). This displays a pop up which asks whether to stay or leave the page. I dont have any idea whats happening and why parent page is refreshed despite adding return false statement in Javascript function. Below is the function. Thanks in advance.

**Code Behind:**

```
       btnAdd.Attributes("onClick") = "return fnShowPopup();"
```

**Javascript:**

```
      function fnShowPopup() {
      var URL='popup URL';
       var retval = '';
      window.showModalDialog(URL,window,'dialogWidth=515px;dialogHeight=230px;status=0;');


       if (ret.val() != '' && ret.val() != null ) {

           var arrValues = retval.split(",");

           objFirstName.value = arrValues[3];
           objLastName.value = arrValues[2];

           objtxtHidFirstName.value = arrValues[3];
           objtxtHidLastName.value = arrValues[2];

           var today = new Date();
           var arrYear = arrValues[4].split("/");
           var birthDay = arrYear[0];
           var birthMonth = arrYear[1];
           var birthYear = arrYear[2];




           return false;
       }
       else {
           return false;
       }

   }



 <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onbeforeunload = function () {
      return false;
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: You should not use showModalDialog ever because it's incompatible with JS's usually asynchronous model, and [it's even being removed from browsers](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/07/disabling-showmodaldialog.html) now.

Comment: What is `ret.val`? And why do you return false in both the `if` and the `else`, rather than just doing it once after the block?

Comment: Hi ret.val is return value from popup. Even though I use at one place, its not working. Just for testing I added in both blocks.

Comment: The same code is working with link button. The original one is image button. I tried everything for image button (onclientclick instead of onclick; event.returnValue = false instead of return false), but nothing seems to be working at this point. I still have to figure out.